# Calculating percentages within a group, given a certain condition

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have a table of customers orders with the following information:

| transaction_id | order_id | merchant_id | merchant_name | on_sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 423hk42b | tuy24u24g | 20022 | This LTD | Yes |
| h64v64h6 | tuy24u24g | 20022 | This LTD | Yes |
| h3v45gh3 | 4i32ghi2i | 22012 | That SAS | No |
| b3k45b44 | 2b34u3bbu | 12032 | Stuff LTD | No |
| jb435bj4 | 1j3bh1hj3 | 12032 | Stuff LTD | Yes |
| jb3k53kb | 12hb3jbb1 | 13121 | More Stuff LTD | Yes |

I need a query to find the percentage of orders on sale for each merchant. The output should look like this:

| merchant_id | merchant_name | total_orders | total_orders_on_sale | perc_sales_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20022 | This LTD | 1381 | 132 | 9.55 |
| 22012 | That SAS | 1313 | 87 | 6.62 |
| 12032 | Stuff LTD | 1323 | 34 | 2.56 |

Any help with this? I tried window functions or WITH statements but I end up with wrong numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select merchant_id, merchant_name,
       count(*) as num_orders,
       sum(case when on_sale = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as num_on_sale,
       avg(case when on_sale = 'Yes' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_on_sale
from t
group by merchant_id, merchant_name;
```

EDIT:

For the revised version, you can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select merchant_id, merchant_name,
       count(distinct order_id) as num_orders,
       count(distinct case when on_sale = 'Yes' then order_id end) as num_on_sale,
       ( count(distinct case when on_sale = 'Yes' then order_id end) * 100.0 /
         count(distinct order_id)
       ) as ratio_on_sale
from t
group by merchant_id, merchant_name;
```

Comment: I forgot to include the transaction_id from the original table. I would need to count the distinct order IDs, as these are the unique identifiers. Therefore, the SUM statement would not work as it would include duplicates. I cannot drop the duplicates as there is additional info that I need. Apologies for the confusion here.